# How to combine two path

Tags: c#, .net

I have the code below and I get the result like this

```
C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Projects\\CA\\Libraries\\ConvertApi-DotNet\\Example\\word2pdf-console\\bin\\Release\\\\..\\..\\..\\..\\test-files\\test.docx
```

The file is found but I would like to show user this path and the formating is not user friendly. I would like to get

```
C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Projects\\CA\\Libraries\\test-files\\test.docx
```

I have tried to use Path.Combine but it do not work.

```
var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string inFile = baseDirectory + @"\..\..\..\..\test-files\test.docx";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of `Path.Combine` and [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx):

```
var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var file = @"..\..\..\..\test-files\test.docx";
string inFile = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(baseDirectory, file));
```

Comment: When I use Path.Combine I get such result "C:\\test-files\\test.docx"

Comment: Ups, sorry, everything works fine. I have removed \ from the file path like in your demo.

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

You say that the file is found.

Then you can use `FileInfo (namespace System.IO)` for that.

#### Sample

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
f.Exists // Gets a value indicating whether a file exists.
f.DirectoryName // Gets a string representing the directory's full path.
f.FullName // Gets the full path of the directory or file.
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - FileInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)